# How to solve Rayleigh Quotient type problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

How to solve Rayleigh Quotient type problem?

$$\max (w+w_0)^tC(w+w_0)
\text{ s.t. } w'w=1,$$

where $w_0$ is given.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you know about $C$?

Comment: real, symmetrical, but maynot be PSD...

Comment: Have you worked in the case $C$ diagonal?

Comment: How to solve that case? Could you please elaborate? Thank you!

Comment: Did you try with Lagrange multiplier? I guess it will work.

Comment: yes, but that's too tedious...